# Create an array based on my function's result

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and scratching my head over this issue:

I used to use the following to grab a bunch of product titles from the page:

**CODE 1:**

```
var productTitles = document.querySelectorAll(".product-title");
```

Then I used the following code to ad a list of these titles to a form's textarea field:

**CODE 2:**

```
var MyTextAreaField = document.querySelector("#my-textarea-field");
MyTextAreaField.value = [...productTitles].map(el=>el.textContent).filter(txt=>txt !== 'None').join('\n');
```

The above worked great, however, I just changed CODE 1 to be a function instead (in order to conditionally return product titles)
*The below code is just a rough example of what it looks like:*

**CODE 3:**

```
var productTitleOne = document.querySelectorAll(".product-title1");
var productTitleTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".product-title2");
var productTitleThree = document.querySelectorAll(".product-title2");

function createProductTitles() {
    if (productTypeOne == null) {
        return productTitleOne.textContent;
    } else if (productTypeTwo == "None") {
        return productTitleTwo.textContent;
    } else {
        return productTitleThree.getAttribute("data-qty") + 'x' + selectionItem.textContent ;
    }
}
```

Problem is, now code 2 no longer works, because it is no longer an Array

So, I tried doing this (adding my function to a variable):

```
var productTitles = createProductTitles();
```

But the following still doesn't work, because it's still not really an array

```
MyTextAreaField.value = [...productTitles].map(el=>el.textContent).filter(txt=>txt !== 'None').join('\n');
```

**So how do I get the result of my function to post to my textarea field?**

Comment: `createProductTitles()` would return something that the spread operator can work with right?

Comment: also what does `createProductTitles` return? I can't help much otherwise(since i cant make a proper array off of what i dont know)

Comment: @TheBombSquad It is just text from all elements with a specific class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value you're returning on `createProductTitles` in the Code 1 you're using the array returned by `var productTitles = document.querySelectorAll(".product-title");` in the Code 3 you're returning the textContent of that selector, i.e.   `return productTitleOne.textContent;`.

It's important to make a distinction between these two codes because they're sending different data types one is returning an `array` and the other is returning a `string`.

So, you need to change your function to return the same the result of the `querySelectorAll` function

```
var productTitleOne = document.querySelectorAll(".product-title1");
var productTitleTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".product-title2");
var productTitleThree = document.querySelectorAll(".product-title2");

function createProductTitles() {
    if (productTypeOne == null) {
        return productTitleOne;
    } else if (productTypeTwo == "None") {
        return productTitleTwo;
    } else {
        return productTitleThree
    }
}
```

and then use your function

```
var productTitles = createProductTitles();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function in CODE 3 needs to change.

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (similar to an array). So it's no good to then try and access the `textContent` property or call `getAttribute()` as you do in that function, both of which should instead be called (if desired) on the individual Nodes in the NodeList.

You can modify that function so that the calls you have made take place on the individual Nodes using the spread operator and `map` function, similarly to how you did in CODE 2:

```
function createProductTitles() {
    if (productTypeOne == null) {
        return [ ...productTitleOne].map( productTitles => productTitles.textContent );
    } else if (productTypeTwo == "None") {
        return [ ...productTitleTwo].map( productTitles => productTitles.textContent );
    } else {
        return [...productTitleThree].map( productTitles => productTitles.getAttribute("data-qty") + 'x' + selectionItem.textContent );
    }
}
```

This function will return an array of string values that you can do with as you wish, such as:

```
createProductTitles().filter(txt=>txt !== 'None').join('\n');
```